# Does Android 7.0+ still support Accessory Mode

Tags: android, arduino, usb, adk

I'm trying to connect my Android phone to Arduino board with USB Host Sheild in order to let Android to launch my app in accessory mode. Basically, it works perfectly well on older devices as `Moto G (2015) - Android 6.0`, `Nexus 5 - Android 6.0.1` and ancient noname tablet with `Android 4.4.2`. But I noticed that on Android 7 and above the app doesn't get launched or no prompt accessory dialog is shown, I tried a few `Huawei` devices, `Xiaomi` all of them have `Android 7` or above.

So, my question, is accessories API still available in `Android 7+`? Thanks in advance.

**UPD.** Seems I got pretty firm evidence that Accessory Mode is still available in Android. Basically, I tested my solution against `Google Pixel 3XL` with `Android 10`. Works well.

Thus my conclusion is, how well that mode supported is up to a manufacturer.
***Is there any ideas how enable this mode, maybe by installing custom ROMs or using some unofficial tweaks. Thanks.***

[image: Android 6.0 and Android 10 screenshots]

Comment: I've used my Huawei P9, Android 7,  to connect to my SD-card reader though an OTG-cable and it works.

Comment: @HarounHajem I presume SD-card rader acted as an accessory, so you needed OTG cable to enable the host mode on tablet/phone? My problem is opposite, Android device acts as peripheral deveice and Arduino is a host.

Comment: ... SD card reader pretty much sounds alike common mass storage. nothing "future" about such a common device class. one can attach 2.5" HDD/SSD drives without the least additional driver.

Answer (score 0):

Of course [it does](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbAccessory.html) - but these stock ROM might lack an application to deal with it. The problem rather seems to be that [usbremotecontrol.com](http://usbremotecontrol.com) went down - and the one snapshot available on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20110201141336/http://usbremotecontrol.com/) looks strange. Just see which application is used on these Android 6.0 devices.

Comment: The screen above shows a default system UI wich appears when there's no app installed which handles USB connectivity. But I don't see this UI on Android 7+.

Comment: As of http://usbremotecontrol.com didn't go down because it is just a fake url. It is optional and palys just an informational role.

Comment: @Ivan that host-name once existed, else archive.org wouldn't know about it. just  create an `intent-filter` for `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED`, then it should become visible to the `UsbManager`.

Comment: Yes, I have `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` in my android app's manifest. There's no problem to start the app on Android versions prior 7. Starting from Android 7 system doesn't want to start my app. So, I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: @Ivan you might be lacking the `uses-feature` or the `usb-accessory` filter (just no clue what to add into there for an Arduino USB host):
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory

Comment: Thanks for your passion helping me:) I do have `uses-feature` and `usb-accessory` but the first one is not essential as it simply helps Google Play to filter out all non-matching devices.

Comment: @Ivan when looking at the comments in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/usb) ...the `usb-accessory` filter values are reported by the attached accessory (so that one can specify an app for a specific accessory). not using wildcard values might prevent the detection; one can only filter once knowing the reported values.